# Как получить большое количество записей из таблицы?

Tags: c#

В таблице находится около 3млн записей при написании следующего запроса

```
using var connection = new MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; Port 33066; Database=myTable; Uid=root; Pwd=root;");
            
connection.Open();

connection.CreateCommand().CommandTimeout = 0;

            var result = connection.Query<Procedure>("SELECT Name, Number FROM " +
                                                     "`procedure` WHERE FederalLaw = 1 " +
                                                     "AND CreatedAtUtc >= '2022-03-20' " +
                                                     "LIMIT 0,1000").ToList();

return result;
```

Я получаю исключение

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "Fatal error encountered during command execution."

SocketException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исключение получаю по таймауту, проходит 30 секунд и получаю исключение

Comment: Зачем вам столько?

Comment: а при запросе TOP 100 работает?
ну в смысле предлагаю понять где проблема: в количестве записей или в коннекте

Comment: `connection.Query<Procedure>` - это что за метод? Расширение, ваше собственное? Что оно делает? Покажите весь код, который задействован. Строка `connection.CreateCommand().CommandTimeout = 0;` не делает ровным счетом ничего. Вы никак не используете экземпляр, созданный методом `CreateCommand()`.

Comment: При Top 100 возникает та же ошибка? Query это метод расширения Dapper. commandTimeOut я вообще пока убрал

Comment: @aepot, я изменил вопрос, посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62721522/12888024, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49453943/12888024